# Monitor doesn't seem to lock the object

Tags: c#, .net, multithreading, mono

I'm trying to implement a basic `Future` class (yeah, I know about `Task` but this is for educational purposes) and ran into strange behavior of `Monitor` class. The class is implemented so that it enters the lock in constructor, queues an action which exits the lock to a thread pool. Result getter checks an instance variable to see if the action is completed and if it isn't, enters lock and then returns the result. Problem is that in fact result getter doesn't wait for the queued action to finish and proceeds anyway leading to incorrect results. Here's the code.

```
// The class itself
public class Future<T>
{
    private readonly Func<T> _f;
    private volatile bool _complete = false;
    private T _result;
    private Exception _error = new Exception("WTF");
    private volatile bool _success = false;
    private readonly ConcurrentStack<Action<T>> _callbacks = new ConcurrentStack<Action<T>>();
    private readonly ConcurrentStack<Action<Exception>> _errbacks = new ConcurrentStack<Action<Exception>>();
    private readonly object _lock = new object();

    public Future(Func<T> f)
    {
        _f = f;
        Monitor.Enter(_lock);
        ThreadPool.QueueUserWorkItem(Run);
    }

    public void OnSuccess(Action<T> a)
    {
        _callbacks.Push(a);
        if (_complete && _success)
            a(_result);
    }

    public void OnError(Action<Exception> a)
    {
        _errbacks.Push(a);
        if (_complete && !_success)
            a(_error);
    }

    private void Run(object state)
    {
        try {
            _result = _f();
            _success = true;
            _complete = true;
            foreach (var cb in _callbacks) {
                cb(_result);
            }
        } catch (Exception e) {
            _error = e;
            _complete = true;
            foreach (var cb in _errbacks) {
                cb(e);
            }
        } finally {
            Monitor.Exit(_lock);
        }
    }

    public T Result {
        get {
            if (!_complete) {
                Monitor.Enter(_lock);
            }
            if (_success) {
                return _result;
            } else {
                Console.WriteLine("Throwing error complete={0} success={1}", _complete, _success); 
                throw _error;
            }
        } 
    }

        // Failing test
        public void TestResultSuccess() {
        var f = new Future<int>(() => 1);
        var x = f.Result;
        Assert.AreEqual (1, x);
    }
```

I'm using Mono 3.2.3 on Mac OS X 10.9.

Comment: Different `Future`s use different locks, so the problem seems to be on your side. You seem to need a shared `_lock`.

Comment: Does Mono have `Task<T>` / `TaskCompletionSource<T>` ? 'cos that would be a lot simpler...

Comment: @Vlad presumably the OP is talking about "in the context of a single future"...

Comment: @MarcGravell: not sure about that: after all, each `Future` is locking only once, in its constructor.

Comment: @MarcGravell I'm implementing futures myself to better understand how they work.

Comment: @Vlad look at the `Result` accessor: it enters

Comment: @synapse I would say that a `ManualResetEvent` is a better metaphor for what you are doing - it is more expensive, though

Comment: @Marc: You're right. I just looked at the code, there is no other access there.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Only the thread that **took** the lock can exit the lock. You can't `Enter` it in the constructor on the calling thread then `Exit` from the thread-pool when it completes - the thread-pool worker ***does not have the lock***.

And conversely: presumably it is the same thread that created the future that is accessing the getter: that is *allowed* to `Enter` again: it is *re-entrant*. Also, you need to `Exit` the same number of times that you `Enter`, otherwise it isn't actually released.

Basically, I don't think `Monitor` is the right approach here.

Comment: Thanks, I kinda missed that part in `Monitor` documentation. What is the proper synchronization primitive to use here?

Comment: @synapse if you just want it to work (i.e. focusing on simple), then `ManualResetEvent`. If you want it to work **efficiently**, then it would probably be something involving interlocked flag checks, etc